# I have a piece of code to run regression but I have no idea why I get a syntax error. the code below

Tags: python

```py
def computeCost(X,y,theta):  
    tobesummed = np.power(((X @ theta.T)-y),2) # he yells invalid syntax no idea why   
    return np.sum(tobesummed)/(2 * len(X))
```

Comment: Maybe a version problem. I think the '@' operator was python 3.5.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including the full error message. I can't reproduce the issue, but I'm using Python 3.6 and @Paul is right.

Answer (score 0):

There's an `@` symbol in there that Python ignores as a decorator. Did you mean `*` or maybe `X.dot(theta.T)`?

```
import numpy as np
def computeCost(X,y,theta):
    tobesummed = np.power(((X * theta.T)-y),2)
    return np.sum(tobesummed)/(2 * len(X))

X, y, theta = np.random.randn(1,10), np.random.randn(1,10), np.random.randn(1,10) 
print(computeCost(X, y, theta))
```

prints `90.03281689585363`.

Comment: thanks. X.dot(theta.T) is a matrix product ( X%*%Y in R?